# Parameterized queries to create a user throwing missing user or role name exception

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, named-parameters

I'm trying to run a `CREATE USER` query on an oracle 12 database using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess library. This query works perfectly without using named parameters. But when i try to use named parameters it looks like the parameters are not passed to the query correctly.

I try the use the parameters with the following code (Note: Im using **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess** library):

```
using(OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(_connectionString)) {
    con.Open();
    using(OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand()) {
        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE USER :username IDENTIFIED BY :password";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("username", "A_TESTUSER");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("password", "A_PASSWORD");
        //cmd.Parameters.Add(":username", "A_TESTUSER"); <- also tried
        //cmd.Parameters.Add(":password", "A_PASSWORD"); <- also tried
        //cmd.Parameters.Add(":username", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "A_TESTUSER"; <- also tried
        //cmd.Parameters.Add(":password", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "A_TESTPASS"; <- also tried
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

which results in the following exception.

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-01935: missing user or role name.
```

The query works when I set when i run the query with the data inline like this

```
cmd.CommandText = "CREATE USER A_TESTUSER IDENTIFIED BY A_PASSWORD";
```

I also tried to use `@` instead of `:` to indicate the parameters without succes. How should I pass the parameters to the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use parameterized **queries** for `CREATE USER`, so it should be

```
cmd.CommandText = String.Format("CREATE USER {0} IDENTIFIED BY \"{1}\"", "A_TESTUSER", "A_PASSWORD");
```

**Note:** Although this solution works, it does not protect you from SQL injection. You should do the needed checks on your inputs in addition to this.

Comment: I read up on the subject a bit and it does seems right, not only for oracle but in general you can not do that for `CREATE USER` and some other query's. Edited in a warning about SQL injection for possible future readers.