# Parameterized queries to create a user throwing missing user or role name exception in Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create users in Oracle database using spring data jpa using native queries but it is failing with the error : missing user or role name exception

```
@Query(value="create user :userName identified by \"Qwert123!\"",nativeQuery=true)
void createUser(@Param("userName")String userName);
```

I stumbled upon a similar question : [Parameterized queries to create a user throwing missing user or role name exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430233/parameterized-queries-to-create-a-user-throwing-missing-user-or-role-name-except)

How can I make the parameterized queries work in my case?

Comment: Do check if the discussion here is similar to your use case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59319530/create-users-in-oracle-mysql-databases-using-springboot-spring-data-jpa

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add an `@Modifying` annotation to that method since it is executing a DDL statement.

But also I don't think the username can be passed as a parameter in SQL, so you actually have to write a custom method where you assemble the statement using String concatenation. 
When doing so make sure that the parameter is properly sanitized and you don't create yourself a [SQL injection vulnerability](https://xkcd.com/327/).